# chartkick JSON data source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, chartkick

I'm trying to get *Chartkick in Rails* to use a JSON data source.
When specifying a chart as `pie_chart User.group(:language).count` I get the expected pie chart.

But when specifying the chart as: `pie_chart /path_to_report_data` from data controller method I get nothing. 
That is, an empty, blank chart (no data in it)

My data controller:

```
  def report    
    @language= User.group(:language).count  
    if request.xhr?  
      render :json => { :language => @language }  
    end  
  end
```

My view:

```
<%= line_chart "/data/report" %>
```

I can see the data is delivered through an Ajax call to the specified controller.

Comment: I think you need to try again with the detailed information because there is very little to go on here.

Comment: Problem seems to be the format of the JSON data. When delivering data as  {"":5,"en":12} I get a decent graph. When using the forementioned format in the controller, which produces {"language":{"":5,"en":12}} I get an empty graph.

Comment: Does this work? `render :json => @language.to_json`

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
def report1
  begin
    @data= [["Cat",6],["Dog",4],["Horse",1],["Parrot",2]]
  rescue Exception => ex
    logger.info('Report 1 error : ' + ex.message)
    @data = nil
  end
  if request.xhr?
    render json: @data
  end
end
```

and in the view:

```
<%= datasource = "/path_to_data_controller/report1"
    line_chart datasource, discrete: true
%>
```

HTH